# Docker.DotNet: OperationCanceledException when querying containerd deamon from inside a container using named pipes

Tags: docker, containerd

I'm running a .NET Core application in a Windows Docker container. The application uses the [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet) library to query the Docker engine. The application communicates with the container host via the named pipe `\\.\pipe\docker_engine`. This works fine on a Windows Server 2019 VM with Docker Desktop. The application can successfully get the list of images that exist on the host.

However, when I try to run this container using containerd on a Windows Server 2019 VM, I get the following exception:

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Docker.DotNet.DockerClient.PrivateMakeRequestAsync(TimeSpan timeout, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, HttpMethod method, String path, IQueryString queryString, IDictionary`2 headers, IRequestContent data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Docker.DotNet.DockerClient.MakeRequestAsync(IEnumerable`1 errorHandlers, HttpMethod method, String path, IQueryString queryString, IRequestContent body, IDictionary`2 headers, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken token)
   at Docker.DotNet.ImageOperations.ListImagesAsync(ImagesListParameters parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

The exception occurs only after a long delay of about 1 - 2 minutes.
This is the command I use to run the container with containerd

```
ctr run -t --rm --mount src=\\.\pipe\containerd-containerd,dst=\\.\pipe\docker_engine docker.io/bhaeussermann/docker-client:latest docker-client
```

If I run it without the `--mount` it fails immediately with a `System.TimeoutException` in the `System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.ConnectInternal()` method. So it seems that with the mount it does connect, but doesn't get much farther.

What am I missing?